# Where should I store number of credits to minimize stealing on my mobile app?

Tags: android, payment

The users of my app will purchase any batches of 10 credits.
My question is, where should I store the current number of credits?

My goals are:

- I want to make it not easy to steal
- I want to make it reliable, I don't
  want users to lose their credits
- I need to tell the user when they run
  out

Ideas:

- Store # credits on phone DB
- Store # credits in server database
- Store # credits in a preference
- Store in all places, and double check on each transaction
- Since the transactions will be low volume, write code to detect excessive behaviors or manually check anything suspicious

I'd like some opinions about how paranoid I should be. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't require the user to log in or authenticate themselves, aren't you vulnerable to attacks on the server (can't the "update balance" call be spoofed?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would store it on both the phone db and on a server db.  The server should be the final word on how many credits a user has, but the phone can be used to warn the user if they are running low, etc.  Whenever a user connects, you should check the values and update the phone's value to reflect the server's.

Answer (score 2):

Storing on a server DB gives you the most control.  The others seem easier to crack into.